# Determine which UIButton fired event in Objective C

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a handful of UIButtons that when pressed fire the method, (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender. Right now I have a document label set for each (btnPlay, btnStop, btnPause), but I don't believe I can access this in Objective C. Is there something I can set in xcode that acts as a variable so when buttonPressed() is fired I know which button (btnPlay, btnStop, or btnPause) fired the event?

Comment: take a look at the Tag property in UIView that UIButton inherits form. its an integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your IBAction to something like the below

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {

    if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Start"]){
        //Do Stuff
    } 

}
```

In this way you can access the sender as a button directly with no issues or type casting required, you can then use the `isEqualToString` method to check the title of the button and run code inside the if statement.

You might also like to consider using the `tag` property which pretty much all Interface Objects have.

```
if(button.tag == 1){
    //Do Stuff
}
```

[image: UIButton Tag]

Switch statements are also a nice clean way of handling different events..

```
switch (button.tag) {
  case 1:
    // Do Something
    break;
  default:
    // Do Default Action
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define which method has to be called when the button pressed after @selector in this case playVideo method.

```
[videoButton setTitle:@"play video" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[videoButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[videoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playVideo:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what the `sender` argument is there for - you can compare it against each of your buttons in a chain of `if` statements to see which one sent that message.

Answer (score 0):

Every `UIButton` has a `titleLabel` property, which is a `UILabel`. Check `sender.titleLabel.text` and compare it against the three strings.

Alternatively, you can also assign each button a tag (generally an integer), either through the Attributes Inspector in Xcode, or using the `tag` property in code. Then check `sender.tag` in your action method.

Comment: In the case of the question, not a problem. Updated my answer with the `tag` property. IMHO I find it easier to set a tag on the button in IB, and check that. Saves me from creating an outlet. Checking `tag` is also more scalable, as the tag doesn't change when you localize the text.